# How to see where my ubuntu is partitioned from my windows disk management?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk

I'm dualbooting Ubuntu with Windows. Is there an easy way to know where my Ubuntu OS and files are from Windows disk management? I want to move everything Ubuntu related into its own disk, separate from windows

[image]

Comment: If you want to move, I'd consider just backing up `/home`, installing the new disk and starting fresh. From there, use `gparted` to format the free space from the old install and allocate to Windows.

Comment: Looking at that I get the feeling that you used the something else option during installation and created partitions for `/swap`, `/home` and `/`. I can guess that your 18GB partition is `/swap`, 60GB is `/` and 165Gb is `/home`. Am I correct?

Comment: So those last 3 partitions belong to Ubuntu

Comment: Please use gparted. It PERFECTLY names partitions. We do not support Windows. This is a windows question on how to use a windows tool.  Besides that: microsoft ignores foreign file systems so we can not answer this question without guessing. Please use gparted dither from a live session or from our installer.

Comment: @Rinzwind But you can guess pretty accurately here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that I get the feeling that you used the `something else` option during installation and created partitions for `/swap`, `/home` and `/`.

If so, I can guess that your 18GB partition is `/swap`, 60GB is `/` and 165Gb is `/home`.

Then, the last 3 partitions in there are your Ubuntu partitions.